# Syntax to specify limit while generating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

in rails, we can generate the model like this

```
rails generate model post title:string body:text published:boolean
```

And the command has following syntax as per the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate)

```
$ rails generate model
Usage: rails generate model NAME [field:type field:type] [options]
```

I am wondering if its possible to specify limit/length for each field as part of `[options]`? Further, what is the use of `[options]` parameter?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can provide the limit with braces:

```
rails g model Session session_id:string{40} user_agent:string{200}
```

Answer (score 3):

In rails 5 I had to use `rails g model User name:"string{16}"`

Comment: This is the way. Note that `"string{16}"` is inside quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the size in the curly braces, which will get transformed into limits

```
rails generate model MyModel some_id:integer{20} some_name:string{255}
some_text:text some_int:integer{1} some_deci:decimal{10,2}
```

**You can also have other data types such as boolean, date, time,
datetime, float, binary etc..**

Options are something like 'do you also need to run migration' or not.